# Complex GROUP BY with Django's ORM

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I have a Django application that tracks electricity consumption and I'm having a hard time trying to come up with a way to use Django's ORM to fetch some information.

My specific use case is this: I have a set of electricity consumption readings, each with a datetime field, consumption and cost (and a few others but these are the relevant ones). I need to sum the consumption and cost values grouped by month, year, electricity meter and electricity price. In other words, I need to be able to get the total energy consumption value and corresponding cost for each month, of each year, for each price (easier to understand if you look at the table further down the post).

This is my `ElectricityReading` model and its parent `Reading` model (separated because we also have consumption readings for water and gas, which also derive from `Reading`):

```python
from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel
# Other imports here...

class Reading(TimeStampedModel):
    meter = models.ForeignKey(Meter)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField() # Terrible property name, I know :)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ElectricityReading(Reading):
    price = models.ForeignKey(ElectricityPrice)
    consumption = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=3,
                                  null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=3, null=True,
                           blank=True, default=None)
```

Right now I'm doing this with this raw SQL, which I build depending on a few parameters:

```sql
SELECT
    (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datetime)) AS reading_date_year,
    (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datetime)) AS reading_date_month,
    SUM(consumption) as total_consumption,
    SUM(cost) as total_cost,
    COUNT(id) as num_readings,
    price_id
FROM electricity_reading
WHERE meter_id IN (10)
    AND datetime >= '2015-10-01 00:00'
    AND datetime <= '2015-12-31 23:59'
GROUP BY reading_date_year, reading_date_month, price_id, meter_id
ORDER BY meter_id, reading_date_year, reading_date_month, price_id
```

This SQL query results in something like the following data (made up values and simplified column names for better formatting):

```
╔══════╦═══════╦═════════════╦══════╦══════════════╦═══════╗
║ year ║ month ║ consumption ║ cost ║ num_readings ║ price ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═════════════╬══════╬══════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2015 ║    10 ║         600 ║  804 ║          456 ║     1 ║
║ 2015 ║    10 ║         728 ║  471 ║         1998 ║     2 ║
║ 2015 ║    10 ║         848 ║  792 ║         1266 ║     3 ║
║ 2015 ║    10 ║         256 ║  705 ║          744 ║     5 ║
║ 2015 ║    11 ║         528 ║  377 ║          630 ║     1 ║
║ 2015 ║    11 ║         016 ║  687 ║         1680 ║     2 ║
║ 2015 ║    11 ║         240 ║  826 ║         1289 ║     3 ║
║ 2015 ║    11 ║         736 ║  522 ║          720 ║     5 ║
║ 2015 ║    12 ║         584 ║  627 ║          608 ║     1 ║
║ 2015 ║    12 ║         776 ║  078 ║         1627 ║     2 ║
║ 2015 ║    12 ║         600 ║  401 ║         1410 ║     3 ║
║ 2015 ║    12 ║         864 ║  842 ║          744 ║     5 ║
╚══════╩═══════╩═════════════╩══════╩══════════════╩═══════╝
```

Using Django's ORM, I think the code I need is something along the lines of the following:

```python
objs = ElectricityReading.objects\
    .filter(
        meter=10,
        datetime__gte='2015-05-01 00:00',
        datetime__lte='2015-08-31 23:59'
    ).only('price_id')\
    .annotate(reading_date_year=YearTransform('datetime'))\
    .annotate(reading_date_month=MonthTransform('datetime'))\
    .annotate(total_consumption=Sum('consumption'))\
    .annotate(total_cost=Sum('cost'))\
    .annotate(num_readings=Count('id'))\
    .order_by('meter_id', 'reading_date_year', 'reading_date_month', 'price_id')
```

But the SQL it generates is not what I need:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    price_id,
    EXTRACT('year' FROM datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Lisbon') AS reading_date_year,
    EXTRACT('month' FROM datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Lisbon') AS reading_date_month,
    SUM(consumption) AS total_consumption, SUM(cost) AS total_cost,
    COUNT(id) AS num_readings
FROM geratriz_electricityreading
WHERE (
    datetime >= '2015-05-01 00:00:00+01:00'
    AND datetime <= '2015-08-31 23:59:00+01:00'
    AND meter_id = 10)
GROUP BY
    id,
    EXTRACT('year' FROM datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Lisbon'),
    EXTRACT('month' FROM datetime AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Lisbon')
ORDER BY meter_id ASC, reading_date_year ASC, reading_date_month ASC, price_id ASC
```

This results in a lot more rows being returned from the database due to not being grouped as I need them to be.

The part of the SQL query I can't seem to replicate with Django's ORM is the `GROUP BY` clause at the end. Django insists on grouping by ID and I can't seem to find a way to make it group by meter_id and price_id.

Given how much time I spent on this already, I'm inclined to say that what I am trying to accomplish simply isn't possible with Django's ORM but I would love that someone would tell me I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#values)

```
objs = ElectricityReading.objects\
    .filter(
        meter=10,
        datetime__gte='2015-05-01 00:00',
        datetime__lte='2015-08-31 23:59'
    .values('price_id')\
    .annotate(reading_date_year=YearTransform('datetime'))\
    .annotate(reading_date_month=MonthTransform('datetime'))\
    .annotate(total_consumption=Sum('consumption'))\
    .annotate(total_cost=Sum('cost'))\
    .annotate(num_readings=Count('id'))\
    .order_by('meter_id', 'reading_date_year', 'reading_date_month', 'price_id')
```

This should group the results on `price_id`. If you were displaying several meters at once instead of `meter=10`, then you could do `values('price_id', 'meter')` and it would group on both fields.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly! Thank you so much! You can't imagine how desperate I was - and it was such a simple solution, how can I have missed that after reading Django's ORM docs so many times?! I owe you a drink! Do you have a tip jar, or a Patreon page or any other way I can show my appreciation?

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I don't have a tip jar, just pay the favour forward and help out another Django user some time :-)

Comment: Will certainly do. Thanks again, Alasdair! :-)